# getting black screen in kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

i am running this kivy app and it is just giving me a black window!
What is the problem? 
I searched for a solution here and I didn't find something.[this is the kivy file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7QRn.png)[this is the python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4eXi.png)

Comment: (it doesn't look good as a text)

Comment: can't you see the images?

Comment: when you paste code you must format it for it select all the code and press Ctrl + K, we want the code to copy it, paste it in our editor and execute it, we do not want to waste time typing a lot of code, if you save us time we could respond quickly , and so you win, if you do not, I see it unlikely that someone will try to help you

Comment: please read [ask], review the [tour] and improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to post your code as text so people can actually copy paste it into their editors.

However, you are getting black screen because you have your code in `__init__()` method of the App class, move that code to `build()` method and you are good to go. For example:

```
class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.sm = ScreenManager()
        self.sm.add_widget(MainScreen(name='main'))
        # and so on
        return self.sm
```

**Why?**

You are calling `TestApp().run()` without creating an instance of the class so `__init__()` is never called. `__init__()` method is called only when you create an instance of the class.